# Spillable MAXIFS

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, automation, maxifs

Good morning to everyone,

I have the following situation:

col i = date (array formula)
col l = profit (array formula)
col k = aggregate profit (array formula)
col z = running max for col i (between 0 and running max), stop and restart when date change.

Like this:
[image]

Before Excel introduced array formulas I had solved it with the following formula:

```
=MAX(0;MAXIFS($V$8:V8;$T$8:T8;I8))
```

with the vba completing the entire column.

After Excel introduced array formulas I had solved it with the following formula:

```
=MAP(i1#;k1#;LAMBDA(DATA;NET;MAX(0;MAXIFS($k$1:NET;$i$1:DATA;DATA))))
```

This solution works, it spill the result for the entire column and the calculations are correct, however on 10,000 lines it is slow.

The question I would like to ask to anyone who wants to answer is the following: is there a faster way, in Excel formula or VBA, to perform this operation?

Thank you all so much, I wish you a good day.

Dario

P.S.
I read a lot of answer for MAXIFS in this community but there are no answer for "spill" MAXIFS. Thank you again

Comment: Have you considered that it is slow because of the various array formulas you have in these columns already? You might be better off creating one formula to spill all of it.

Comment: Hello VBasic2008, yes I considered, in fact my formula =MAP(i1#;k1#;LAMBDA(DATA;NET;MAX(0;MAXIFS($k$1:NET;$i$1:DATA;DATA)))) spill all over the column. Or maybe I don't understood whats you mean.

Comment: Is your data sorted by date as in your example?

Comment: Hello Rory, yes is sorted, without any formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A Running Max: Spill MAXIFS Using SCAN Instead

```
=LET(ddata,I8:I27,aData,K8:K27,
    dc,ddata=VSTACK(INDEX(ddata,1)-1,DROP(ddata,-1)),
    SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(ddata)),LAMBDA(sr,r,LET(
        a,INDEX(aData,r),
        IF(INDEX(dc,r),IF(a>sr,a,sr),IF(a<0,0,a))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, VBasic2008, really smart solution, works really well, and very fast. I would not have been able to arrive at this solution, alone, and with my current knowledge. Many thanks. Have a good afternoon. Thank you.

Comment: That's nice, I'm thinking that your method using vstack/drop to compare previous element is neater than doing what I have tended to do which is using index(ddate,r-1)=index(ddate,r) or something because of course it doesn't work for r=1 and that has to be a special case.

Answer (score 1):

With sorted data, you could also use something like:

```
=LET(iData,I2:I15,kData,K2:K15,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(I2:I15)),LAMBDA(s,c,IF(c=1,MAX(s,INDEX(kData,c)),MAX(IF(INDEX(iData,c)=INDEX(iData,c-1),s,0),INDEX(kData,c))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another formula:

```
=LAMBDA(dates, aggreg, DROP(REDUCE(0, UNIQUE(dates), 
   LAMBDA(a,b, VSTACK(a, SCAN(0,FILTER(aggreg, dates=b),
   LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y>x,y,x)))))),1))($J$5:$J$24,$K$5:$K$24)
```

[image: Peak]